# How can I become more attentive and focused at my job?

Tags: work-environment, distractions, task-management

My job is usually concerned with Data Entry/Analysis. I work with a lot of data in Excel spreadsheets, prepare lot of Reports, requirement documents. I have to remember a lot of facts/things . I write them down in my notebook, still I have noticed that when I am doing my task, I don't even look at the notebook and enter wrong data, for example into a Web signup form. It causes serious mistakes, for which I am sharply rebuked and even can lose my job.

There is also lot of distractions from my colleagues. Someone or the other is calling me all the time for some meeting or a task. I can't say no to that also, as it's a part of my job! Please provide my some techniques/method which can help me be laser focused on my current task, so that I don't leave room for serious mistakes. Also provide guidance on productivity or time management and link reference material.

Comment: For data entry, mistakes are inevitable. You really have to place some safe guards in to make sure they don't end up going out. For example, if you fill out a form, you could fill it out twice by different people or at different times, and only submit the final version when both drafts match.

Answer (score 6):

Data entry task is repetitive task and as human being mistakes always there but there are many ways to improve focus and productivity.

Some suggestions are given below :

1. Do not work continues for long hours ,**Take small breaks between work**. Take a coffee/tea break in between. It will relax your mind. 15 minutes break is enough after every 3 hours.
2. **Create checklist** of your daily task and follow it. Tick points when you done it. Check list is very good practice and have effective result.
3. Create **check list of your mistakes** as well. So next time when you refer same checklist , it will help you to reduce repetitive mistakes.
4. If you have daily job of form filling , excel entries then **try to automate** it. Because machine can work more effectively & fast than human being. In excel you can automate your tasks using macro, formulas, VBA script etc.
5. Do not try to complete data entry to fast , **Accuracy is more important** than speed. Speed should be there but no meaning of it if data entry is incorrect.
6. **Do not work under pressure** , Keep your mind cool and work in effective way.
7. **Avoid unnecessary meetings**, Do not deny for meeting directly but if you feel that some meetings does not require you then you can request your manager to skip those meetings.

Hope above will help you to improve your focus on work.

Comment: I'd note that the required break duration and interval differs between people. Some people can indeed continue for 3 hours on end without losing focus, others lose focus after 1,5 hours already. Some can take a 5 minute break to grab a beverage and clear their mind, others require more tome to become fully productive again. Other than that, +1 from me, especially for the automation: if you can automate a task and verify that your automation executes the task correctly, you've won both time and accuracy.

Comment: @Cronax - Thanks a lot. You are right that people take break as per their mind capacity , I just wanted to give here break example.:)