# How can i become more alert while doing my work?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, project-management, productivity, task-management

I work as QA analyst in a software company. My work involves testing of applications. I have worked on lot of small projects. The problem i have started to face is of low alertness. For example i was writing a test report for one of my clients., i was asked by my colleague to omit some data from it. I nodded and then forgot that thing. Luckily he saw it and amended it. There are many countless incidents which make me feel very lost and distracted. It would be really helpful if you could provide me some high practical tips to become more focused and alert while performing my tasks.

Comment: No...please dont mark this question as duplicate...i need advice.

Comment: @deep88 the whole point of marking a duplicate is there might already be answers out there that you can use as your advice.

Comment: @deep88, so could you update this question to show how the answers of the linked questions don't solve your issue? Having more information could be helpful here.

Comment: Is it appropriate to link to a duplicate question when that question itself has been marked as a duplicate?  Would it not be better to link to the original, non-duplicate question?

Comment: don't smoke anything that might affect your short term memory during working hours

Comment: Software QA is notoriously boring and part or all of it can be automated. Since it's boring you, why not learn to automate it, or at least the most mindlessly boring, routine bits.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad, but here's a stab at it.

1. As Joe Strazzere suggested in a comment, consider a physician.  This may be a medical issue.  (This may include mental health as well - there's a lot of that going around)
2. Make sure you're getting enough sleep.
3. Reduce your intake of caffeine, especially at the end of the day.
4. Alcohol can also mess up sleep schedule and attention.  If you imbibe, try backing off for a little while.
5. Consider - does this job matter to you, or is it just a paycheck?  It's possible that you are in the wrong job/company/industry.  If you're not motivated, attention to detail is very difficult.
6. Read the answers to [How can I become more attentive and focused at my job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/59814/10905). They are definitely relevant.
7. Also read the answers to [Are there any strategies you can use to remain focused when working in a open plan environment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/778/10905)  Even if they're not exact duplicates, they contain useful info that might be applicable